# Identify pipe connecting to nothing in basement (fireplace/hvac/unsure)

Tags: hvac, pipe, fireplace

I'm remodeling my basement and came across the following pipe connected to a duct or something. It looks like it connects to something and, maybe, that something is the fireplace. At the least, it goes up around the same location as the fireplace. I'll remove it if it isn't doing anything. Anyone have any idea if this could be a fireplace component and, if so, how to test to see that it is without cutting up the floor? [image: Picture of where it connects][image: goes to nothing]

Tags are my best guess as to what this relates to.

Comment: Look inside the fireplace, there may be a fresh air intake. Take photos if you are unsure.

Comment: I would think it may be an air intake, if you close the house up and have a fire going a piece of light weight paper like tissue paper may be sucked to it, at least that could provide an idea it is usually required on modern wood stoves and fire places to have outside air intakes.

Comment: The operative word there is "outside". Get on a ladder, get another person sticking their head in the fireplace and play 'telephone'. Then make it go where it's supposed to and put a bird screen.

Comment: Would think the pipe was added to reduce/stop the fireplace from pulling cold air up from the basement, when in use.  As other have said, put it though an outside wall.  Would have the outside section pointing down or make a loop(like an upside down P-trap), cold air does not like going up.

Comment: I'm very curious about the "truss" or "header" framing in the second pic to the right of the big white pipe. Normally, one would put the cripple stud _under_ the thing it's to be supporting, not next to it. While this doesn't appear to be load bearing in any way, it looks... odd, at best.

Comment: Undo the duct tape and look up there with a bright flashlight. It could be an added vent to a bathroom and was never completed.  It looks like a wire is going up there too. Check it out.

Comment: All that work and they used the cheap 'duct' tape that eventually dries up and fails.  Maybe it's for a future laundry room and it's the dryer vent.

Comment: These comments have all been very helpful. I'll respond once I know what the thing is and let everyone know what works. @FreeMan, no clue, but wouldn't be shocked if it was nonsensicle. Found a live outlet behind a wall, too. This is preexisting work.

Answer (score 3):

**Best bet:** an incomplete fresh outside air intake so that your fireplace wouldn't be sucking heated air out of your house. The "outside" part of it does not seem to have been done if it just stops there in the basement.

**Alternatively:** it may be pulling cool basement  air into a "heatilator" arrangement around the fireplace, with warm air venting above the fireplace, and circulation eventually moving cooler warmed air back down to the basement.

If you can't follow it by ear, a fog machine or "canned smoke" might be helpful in tracing the air path as into *.vs.* around the fireplace.